# Preparing Mysql Database for Joomla or PHP Website

Tags: php, mysql, database, joomla, populate

I have a Mysql database of 500+ Real Estate Listings which I am looking to load into an empty Joomla Extension (this may apply to any PHP Script).

I have copied the structure and convention of each table the extension uses - with the idea of either exporting or simply deleting the original tables and replacing them with mine.

Upon testing this concept I end up with a complete mess - My guess is that some of the tables need to have information stored in them before updating others either by Java or PHP.

For example; Client_Info table has to be saved before Property_ Info.

PHPAdmin does not show me the extensions table relationships ( joins, queries etc) I presume they are dealt with through Javascript or PHP.

My Question is what steps do I need to perform to  populating the extensions Database.

The extension provider has been saying for months that they were going to provide this process.

If the question is too broad I would be satisfied either with some links or **keywords** so I can get a handle on the topic.

Comment: Installing it is a total mess. Do you have an install script (in php) or just sql back up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I would try to solve this:

1. Check how many db tables the extensions uses
2. Check in what sequence you would add entries through the web interface (e.g. make category first, then create new record, etc.)
3. Search the extension code for the table names (without prefix) in order to find out how the code handles the data
4. Check if there are any other sources of information the extension uses, like a config file (ini, xml, ...)
5. Build an import script that covers these logics

Comment: very cool . Liked the 'without prefix' shows precision and inspires confidence... So I'm off to write my first script  - Thx

Answer (score 0):

If it's joomla than it's definitely php. What you need to do is get through the posting procedure files of that joomla component and see what must be entered and what tables get filled. And then you'll have steps for creating an import script.